# Word2Vec model on Italian Wikipedia

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I would like to use a Word2Vec model pre-trained on Italian wikipedia. Do you know if it already exists or, if it does not, if it would be possible to build one? I have no such experience with gensim, but I would need to use a good model with word-embeddings for Italian language.

Thank you for all your answers.

Answer (score 1):

FastText has released an Italian word embedding that you can download [here](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html)